# obtain the right side from left side

Tags: inequality

Sorry if my question is rudimentary because my mathematical knowledge is low.
How to obtain the right side from left side?

[image]

Comment: are $M$, $N$ both greater than $0$? Signs are important with inequalities...

Answer (score 2):

$$M \gt \frac N2 \iff \frac N2 \lt M \iff N\lt 2M \iff \frac NM \lt 2, \;\;\text{ provided } M\gt 0$$

We can only conclude that $1 \leq \dfrac NM$ if we also know that $N \geq M$.

Comment: @amWhy: needs another UV +1

Answer (score 2):

$$M>\frac{N}{2}\Leftrightarrow 2M>N\Leftrightarrow2>\frac{N}{M}\Leftrightarrow \frac{N}{M}<2,$$ for $M,N>0.$
Now we have:
$$\frac{N}{M}<2\Rightarrow \frac{N}{M}>1 \text{or} \frac{N}{M}=1,$$ for $M=N,$ i.e $\frac{N}{M}\geq 1.$ Finally:$$1\leq\frac{N}{M}<2$$

Comment: Why do not we consider the case of N < M? for example : N = -2 and M = 2

Comment: Because, in the case $N<M$ we have: $\frac{N}{M}=\frac{-2}{2}=-1>1$,because we have $\frac{N}{M}>1,$ so they can thus act, or because in case $N<M$ qe have $\frac{N}{M}<1$ and should receive $\frac{N}{M}>1$

Comment: @user106557 and Madrit:  We can have that $N<M$: Suppose $N = 1, M = 2:$ then $M = 2 > \frac N2 = \frac 12$, and it also holds that $\frac NM = \frac 12 \lt 2$. So it is possible for $N < M$, and for what we are given to be true. But it does not hold then that $1\leq \frac NM = \frac 12 \geq 1$! So $1\leq \frac NM $ if and only if $N \geq M$, as I state in my answer: $$\text{We do have }\quad \frac NM \lt 2, \;\;\text{ provided } M\gt 0.$$
But we can only conclude that $1 \leq \dfrac NM$ if we also know that $N \geq M$.